# Passing IDs of table rows

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and not long ago I ask the following question:

I have a normal HTML table where each row has its own id. What I want to achieve is that each time I click a link in a row the id for that row should be stored in a variable and later passed to a function. Let's say I click row#1 then id#1 should be passed and so on... How can I achieve this?

I got a very good answer. This example works in jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/9HEQk/

But if I copy the JavaScript and the table exactly like it is into a HTML file the whole thing just doesn't work and I can't find the answer. Could someone help me again please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the row id so why not using a simple code like this:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="table-one">
    <tr id="row-one">
        <td><a href="JavaScript: void(0)" id="one" onClick="saveRow( 1 )">one</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-two">
        <td><a href="JavaScript: void(0)" id="two" onClick="saveRow( 2 )">two</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
var lastRowId = -1;

function saveRow( id )
{
   lastRowId = id;
}
```

Maybe I didn't fully understand what you asked?

Rotem